# How to assemble an array of matching dates for a line graph of 30-, 60-, and 90-day stretches?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, range, chart.js

I'm trying to render a line graph using chartjs showing dates from a JSON file, and it needs to have the following characteristics:

1. The X axis must be 16 different dates spread across 30, 60, or 90 days (changeable through a dropdown menu)
2. The Y axis shows the number of patient encounters that took place on each date
3. There are two arrays that will be shown as lines in the chart: one for total encounters, and one for first encounters with patients (i.e., new patients/first visits)

I've gotten the chart to show more or less the total and first encounters, but the higher the day range, the more sparse the data is because the dates in the JSON file often fall in between the 16 date values. My main question is, how can I make sure to add these in-between encounters to their closest match in the X axis? This is basically what I've come up with so far, and it doesn't work:

The function that creates the X axis:

```js
function calcLabels() {
    timeAxis = [];
    timeAxisDates = [];
    if (!isYearView) {
        numberOfGraphValues = 16;
        switch (tabDays) {
            case 30:
                timeInterval = 2;
                break;
            case 60:
                timeInterval = 4;
                break;
            case 90:
                timeInterval = 6;
        }
        let dateForArray = new Date();
        for (let i = 1; i < numberOfGraphValues; i++) { //Find 16 dates spread across the number of months
            timeAxisDates.push(new Date(dateForArray));
            let theDate = dateForArray.getDate();
            if (theDate === 1 || theDate <= timeInterval || i === (numberOfGraphValues-1)) {
                theDate = nameMonth(dateForArray.getMonth()) + ' ' + theDate; //Add the month name if it's the 1st or 2nd day of it
            }
            dateForArray.setDate(dateForArray.getDate() - timeInterval);
            timeAxis.push(theDate)
        }
        timeAxisDates.reverse();
        timeAxis.reverse();
    } else { //Is YTD
        numberOfGraphValues = 12;
        timeAxis = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];
        timeAxisDates = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12];
    }
}
```

The problematic code that should be finding all the encounters and assigning them to dates:

```js
function countEncounters() {
    resetPatients();
    let patientData = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('patient_data'));
    let index = 0;
    for (let patient in patientData) {
        if (patient === '00000000') continue;
        //Find the encounter
        let isNewPatient = true;
        for (let encounter in patientData[patient].patientEncounters) {
            let formattedDate = formatDate(patientData[patient].patientEncounters[encounter].encounterDate); //This function simply changes the date form from a JSON string, e.g. "20181012" to a date object
            formattedDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
            patientEncounters[index] = {"date": formattedDate};
            if (isNewPatient) firstPatientEncounter[index] = {"date": formattedDate};
            isNewPatient = false;
            index++;
        }
    }
    //Find the date on the axis in the graph
    if (!isYearView) {
        for (let i = 0; i < timeAxis.length; i++) {
            for (let date in patientEncounters) {
                let dayAfter = [];
                for (let j=0; j<timeInterval; j++){
                    dayAfter.push(timeAxisDates[i].getDate() + j)
                }
                // dayAfter.setDate(timeAxisDates[i].getDate() + 1);
                if (patientEncounters[date].date.getMonth() === timeAxisDates[i].getMonth()) { //compare months and days
                    if (patientEncounters[date].date.getDate() === timeAxisDates[i].getDate() || checkRange(patientEncounters[date].date.getDate(), dayAfter)) {
                        totalPatients[i]++
                    }
                }
                if (firstPatientEncounter[date] != null) {
                    if (firstPatientEncounter[date].date.getMonth() === timeAxisDates[i].getMonth() ) { //compare months and days
                        if (firstPatientEncounter[date].date.getDate() === timeAxisDates[i].getDate() || checkRange(patientEncounters[date].date.getDate(), dayAfter)) {
                            newPatients[i]++
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else { //YTD
        for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
            for (let date in patientEncounters) {
                if (patientEncounters[date].date.getMonth() === timeAxisDates[i + 1]) {
                    if (lastYear) {
                        if (patientEncounters[date].date.getFullYear() === (year - 1)) {
                            totalPatients[timeAxisDates[i]]++
                        }
                    } else {
                        totalPatients[timeAxisDates[i]]++
                    }
                    if (firstPatientEncounter[date] != null) {
                        if (firstPatientEncounter[date].date.getMonth() === timeAxisDates[i + 1]) {
                            if (lastYear) {
                                if (firstPatientEncounter[date].date.getFullYear() === (year - 1)) {
                                    newPatients[timeAxisDates[i + 1]]++
                                }
                            } else {
                                newPatients[timeAxisDates[i]]++
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

function checkRange(date, array){
for (let i=0; i<array; i++){
    if (date === array[i]) return true
}
return false
}
```

I haven't finished Year to Date yet, but it's also having bugs, so any tips on how to make that work would be appreciated as well. Finding out what I'm doing wrong in the days view will likely fix that already, though.

Comment: It would help greatly if you broke your problem down to the simplest form that shows a single specific issue rather than attempting. See  [*How to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: As far as I can see, you want to generate histograms of 2, 4 and 6 days duration over the 30, 60 and 90 day intervals, then drop the encounter dates into the right bucket. You should also supply some sample data and expected output. Also, I can't see where you declare *patientEncounters* or assign it a value so `patientEncounters[index] = {"date": formattedDate}` should throw an error.